# Spark-cassandra-connector native protocol version

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Is there any setting for native protocol version in Spark Cassandra connector or it by default communicate the best version (V4 or V5) at the connection time. I am seeing a dip in my Cassandra performance dip for reports generated via spark while running on Cassandra 4 as compared to running same setup with Cassandra 3.11.x. So was apprehensive that what could cause it. So wanted to know is there any property like native protocol version which can be set to see performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark Cassandra Connector relies on the Java driver to negotiate the best supported protocol version.  But you can also enforce a specific version by using a custom [driver configuration profile](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.2/manual/core/configuration/) - specify its name via `spark.cassandra.connection.config.profile.path` configuration.  See the Spark Cassandra Connector [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md#connecting-using-an-astra-cloud-bundle-or-driver-profile-file-since-scc-25) for specifics on how to specify a file name.